# XDomainRequest post data not displaying

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, xdomainrequest

I can't get POST data trough Internet Explorer XDomainRequest.
Simply nothing is showing up..

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/itimeheke/AV9vs/)

*parim.ee/test.php* just prints out `$_POST` and `$_REQUEST` variable like so:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *', true);
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *", true);

echo "var_export(\$_POST):\n";
var_export($_POST);

echo "\n\n";

echo "var_export(\$_REQUEST):\n";
var_export($_REQUEST);
```

Comment: Instead of '`'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'`, try replacing `*` with the referer URL. Can you also confirm that the request is hitting your server?

Answer (score 1):

**FOUND A SOLUTION:**

Instead of using `$_POST` i have to use `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`.